# viewing a txt file from a textview

Tags: java, android

i want to show a txt file by a text view and i use of this code

```
TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_HelpText);
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quizhelp);
String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
helpText.setText(strFile);
```

in api 8 i have tested and this code works fine but in my new project that i have setted min sdk to 15 , can NOT recognize inputStreamToString method ! what method i should use instead this ?
tnx

Comment: Where is `inputStreamToString()` defined? It's not part of the Android SDK, so you should have control where it lives, when it's called, how it's called etc.

Comment: in sdk 8 it recognizes and is usable ,this is needed import java.io.IOException; but ins sdk 15 this import cant help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BufferedReader`:

```
TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_HelpText);
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.quizhelp);

BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iFile));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String line;

try {
    while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append(newline);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

helpText.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: thank you very much , Mattia and MChaker your both codes works good but ,in Mattia's code all my file strings attach toghether not any \n character works but in MChaker's code all enter characters work fine

Comment: @BehnamRanjbar Thank you for pointing that out, I just updated my answer with support for new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView_HelpText);
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream ins = res.openRawResource(R.raw.quizhelp);

    byte[] b = new byte[ins.available()];
    ins.read(b);
    helpText.setText(new String(b));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @BehnamRanjbar Have you tried my code? I guess it works with sdk 15.

Comment: thank you very much , Mattia and MChaker your both codes works good but ,in Mattia's code all my file strings attach toghether not any \n character works but in MChaker's code all enter characters work fine